# OpenMP conditional critical

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

First, bear in mind that I'm not a very frequent user of OpenMP... OK?

Now that we're past that, is there such thing as a conditional `critical`?
I am particularly interested in this line inside a parallelized `for` loop:

```
(...)

    #pragma omp critical
    myMapOfVectors[i].push_back(someNumber);

(...)
```

I would like to have it `critical` *if and only if* the threads running this specific line have the same `i` (because as I have been experiencing – and please correct me here if I'm wrong – multiple threads pushing back to the same `vector` is not thread safe and might cause a `segfault`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to have a [lock](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#OMP_SET_LOCK) for each index `i`.

```
// before you parallel region
std::vector<omp_lock_t> myLocks(myMapOfVectors.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < myLocks.size(); ++i) {
    omp_init_lock(myLocks+i);
}

...

omp_set_lock(myLocks[i]);
myMapOfVectors[i].push_back(someNumber);
omp_unset_lock(myLocks[i]);

...

// after your parallel region
for (size_t i = 0; i < myLocks.size(); ++i) {
    omp_destroy_lock(myLocks+i);
}
```

A critical section is essentially just a single lock, by having multiple locks you are in essence emulating having a separate critical section for each index.

Just keep in mind that locking can be quite slow (especially if there are collisions). You may be able to achieve better performance if you can partition your work ahead of time (i.e., each thread works on a different set of indexes `i`, or each thread has its own copy of `myMapOfVectors` that get combined later).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I like your solution, but I'd expect some directive to do the heavy lifting for me. I mean, this is why we have OpenMP, no? :P Not a complaint towards you, just a critic to OpenMP...

Comment: Because pragmas are compile time directives, they cannot be used to synchronize on dynamically allocated heap objects (in the general case at least). If you implement your own stack object (with a fixed memory allocation), you could use `#pragma omp atomic` to insert elements internally (the insertion would not be atomic, but incrementing the count would be).

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833568/9349211). You can derive the std::vector class to implement a suitable atomic_push_back method.

Your example code could then be written as

```
std::vector<omp_vector<...>> myMapOfVectors;
(...)

    myMapOfVectors[i].atomic_push_back(someNumber);

(...)
```

with no needs of any critical region. Note that the internal lock only acts if different threads push back at the same i-th omp_vector